# how to create a copy constructor to a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, copy, subclass

i am trying to write  a class which has an array of a subclass in the same project, and when i am trying to write a method that will add a new object to the array on condition that this object is not already in the array, and also if the specific cell is free, so the object will enter to the array.
but the problem is that i need to insert a variable to this method which is the copy constructor's object.
the problem is that in the subclass i don't know how to write the copy constructor.
so i will give a short example of 2 classes and you will show me how to write a copy constructor with them :

```
public class Food
{
private String _foodName;
public Food(String foodName)
{
_foodName=foodName;
}
public String getFoodName()
{
return _foodName;
}
public void showName()
{
System.out.println("The food's name is: " +_getFoodName());
}
}

public class Apple extends Food
{
private int _numOfApples;
public Apple(String name, int numOfApples)
{
super(name);
_numOfApples=numOfApples;
}
public Apple(Apple other)
{
????
}
}
```

how does the copy constructor should looks like ?
thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

By invoking the other constructor. Like,

```
public Apple(Apple other) {
    this(other.getFoodName(), other._numOfApples);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I cannot help you properly because i cannot understand entirely what you are trying to do but at least i can help you correct some mistakes in your code:

```
public class Food
{
     private String food;

     public Food(String foodName)
     {
          food = foodName;
     }
     public String getFoodName()
     {
          return food;
     }
     public void showName()
     {
          System.out.println("The food's name is: " + getFoodName());
     }
 }

 public class Apple extends Food
 {
      private int numOfApples;

      public Apple(String name, int numberOfApples)
      {
           super(food);
           numOfApples=numberOfApples;
      }
      public Apple(Apple copy)
      {
           this.name = copy.name;
           this.numOfApples = copy.numOfApples;
      }
 }
```

Hope this helps.